# What is the use of an android folder in a react native app?

Tags: react-native

I have created an app with react-native init app_name and after the app was finished to be created I was looking in the app and trying to understand the folders contained in the app,like android ios node_modules but I couldn't find an resource explaining those folders. I would like to know the function of each folder. So if you have any links please share them, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-Native is a cross-platform framework for developing Android & iOS apps using Javascript. An app written in React-Native contains 2 important threads: a Javascript thread to run your business logic, and a main UI thread for rendering. Interaction between the business logic thread and UI thread is done via a bridge, which is also provided by React-Native framework.

Since Android & iOS uses different languages for the native layer (Java & C++), the logic for these platforms (UI thread, bridge, etc.) must be separated. Of course, those logic should be separated from the Javascript part, too. That's why we have `android` and `ios` folders.

React-Native project uses npm as default package manager for all its Javascript libraries, and by default, all packages are downloaded and stored in `node_modules` folder. If you work in other NodeJS projects, then you will see this folder often.

Sadly, I cannot find any official documentation with further explanation about folder structure of React-Native project, and I am not a native developer, so I can only give you some links with related information.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#js-frame-rate-javascript-thread

https://www.simform.com/react-native-app-performance/

Hope it help.